# Laravel array to json format

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

So I'm trying to convert a Laravel array into `json` so I can then manipulate it through javascript. Im not sure how this is achieved correctly. Here is the code, so far

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 tag">
            <h4><strong><a href="{{{ $post>postName }}}">#{{String::title($posts->postName) }}</a></strong></h4>
        </div>
     </div>
    <!-- ./ post title -->
   </div>    
</div>
<hr />
@endforeach


<script type="text/javascript">
   var data = "{{ ($posts) }}"; // ??
   console.log(data);
</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could return an json_encoded array from the controller like so:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    $json = json_encode($posts);
    return View::make('posts.index', compact('posts', 'json'));
}
```

Which you then can work on in your view like you'd like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = {{ $json }};
    console.log(data);
</script>
```

Also, if you have sensitive fields on your post model, you should exclude these in the model class to prevent them to show in your javascript inspector:

```
class Post extends \Eloquent {
    ...

    protected $hidden = array(
    'id',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at'
    );

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you looking for "high-level" way to convert plain array to json, you can use laravel collections.

```
collect(['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3])->toJson();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use Eloquents built in function [`toJson`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L782) to get your rows as json.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var data = "{{ $posts->toJson() }}";
   console.log(data);
</script>
```

If there's some fields you don't want to include, add the field to the `hidden` property in your model as [Jimmy mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28524412/397195).

Comment: This is cleaner, use this in combination with the hidden field in model.

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   let data = @json($posts);
   console.log(data);
</script>
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. More info under Rendering JSON : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to do all that, just use the php inbuilt function json_encode

```
$json = json_encode($posts);
    echo $json;

<script type="text/javascript">
   var data = "$json"; // ??
   console.log(data);
</script>
```

Comment: Hey I tried that but it just prints empty braces. I need the above code since it displays all the post titles but also I then need to do some client side processing with those same posts. The second aspect is what I cant figure out

Comment: json_encode will ensure that json data is properly encoded from an array, once encoded you can use json_decode function to generate a json object which can be further used to display specific object values